# When need to use FreeHGlobal()?

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

If I use `Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi` as following:

```
char *src = (char *)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(this->Textbox1->Text).ToPointer();
```

Do I need to use `Marshal::FreeHGlobal()` ? And if, What parameter should I give ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to MSDN - yes, you need to call FreeHGlobal. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.stringtohglobalansi%28v=VS.100%29.aspx:

> Because this method allocates the unmanaged memory required for a
>   string, always free the memory by calling FreeHGlobal

Comment: But what argument do I need to give `Marshal::FreeHGlobal()` in my case!

Comment: You allocated memory using StringToHGlobalAnsi. And you should free this memory according to documentation.

Comment: Yah, But in my case I don't have a name for the part of memory needed to be free! So, I don't have specific parameter for `FreeHGlobal()`!

Comment: Cast the char* back to IntPtr.

Comment: You just need to save result of StringToHGlobalAnsi in separate variable. You don't have separate variable now but anyway you have allocated memory (without references to it.

Comment: @HansPassant: Can you please explain more!

Comment: Marshal::FreeHGlobal((IntPtr)src);

Answer (score 2):

The C# string conversion functions are absolutely horrible by C++ standards.

C++/CLI has its own string conversion helpers, which follow the rules of RAII to automatically clean up temporary buffers.  Just use:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <msclr\marshal.h>

using namespace msclr::interop;

marshal_context converter;
const char *src = converter.marshal_as<const char*>(Textbox1->Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

Attach my 2 practice code for Marshal::FreeHGlobal
Be noted that the argument of Marshal::FreeHGlobal() are different!!

```
string CPlusPlusString;
String ^VisualString;
VisualString=textBox1->Text;
CPlusPlusString=(char *)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(VisualString).ToPointer();
Marshal::FreeHGlobal(Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(VisualString));
```

---

```
char *CString;
String ^VisualString;
VisualString=textBox1->Text;
CString = (char*) Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(VisualString).ToPointer();
Marshal::FreeHGlobal(IntPtr(CString));
```

Comment: Different from what? `Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi` returns an `IntPtr` and that's what `Marshal::FreeHGlobal` takes as an argument.